# Incorrect item gets selected when starting a drag on an item in an ItemsControl

Tags: wpf, drag-and-drop, itemscontrol

I am implementing a `DragDrop` framework for WPF (which incidentally you can find [here](http://code.google.com/p/gong-wpf-dragdrop/)).

I have a problem in that when the user `MouseDown`s on an `ItemsControl` we don't know immediately if they intended to click the item to select it, or to begin a drag. If the user clicks an item and then quickly moves the cursor, another item other than the clicked item can become selected before we determine that a drag has started (especially if clicking on the item freezes the UI for a short time to load data etc).

I think this problem didn't exist in WinForms as dragging the mouse with the button held down didn't cause another item to become selected - the selection was made only on the item on which the click occurred.

In the `PreviewMouseDown` event I can set the `e.Handled` property to prevent another item becoming selected, which works fine if the user actually *did* intend to start a drag, but then they can't actually select the item.

Anyone know how to handle this?

Answer (score 0):

Store/use the point at which they originally moused-down, and use that to resolve the item to drag.

Comment: I was doing that, but then the item being dragged doesn't match up with the item selected in the ItemsControls. Confusing for the user: which item are they actually dragging?